Unable to bond two 2.5 Gbps Realtek RTL8156 Ethernet adapters via LACP on Linux
I'm in the process of upgrading my Ethernet to 10 Gbps to speed up the
connectivity of my local network. Regretfully, a machine on my network has
ran out of PCIe slots, so a native 10 GbE PCIe adapter is not an option. A
USB adapter is the only feasible alternative - as 5 Gbps Ethernet switches
and USB adapters are hard to find and expensive, the decision was made to run
the server with two 2.5 Gbps Ethernet to USB 3 adapters based on the Realtek RTL8156
chipset, which is readily-available. Then, they're together at the Ethernet level
using link aggregation in a LAG/LACP, and connected to a 2.5/10 Gbps switch.
These USB adapters can be recognized by Linux as the following. I've also determined
beforehand that both adapters can operate independently at 2.5 Gbps by assigning an
IP address to each NIC and running a iperf3 test.
$ dmesg
[    5.118103] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    5.138434] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8156, bcdDevice=31.04
[    5.138436] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[    5.138438] usb 4-4: Product: USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
[    5.138439] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    5.138440] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 401300ÿÿÿÿ
[    6.970319] cdc_ncm 4-4:2.0: MAC-Address: 00:e0:4c:68:10:e6
[    6.970325] cdc_ncm 4-4:2.0: setting rx_max = 16384
[    6.970356] cdc_ncm 4-4:2.0: setting tx_max = 16384
[    6.984099] cdc_ncm 4-4:2.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:0a:00.3-4, CDC NCM (NO ZLP), 00:e0:4c:68:10:e6

# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN

The machine in question is running a Linux hypervisor (Proxmox), and two network interfaces
are recognized as enx00e04c680152 and enx00e04c6810e6 (I believe udev/systemd generated
the names based on their MAC addresses). To bond two interfaces together, on Proxmox
I used the following settings:
Linux Bond
* Name: bond0
* Autostart: Yes
* Slaves: enx00e04c680152 enx00e04c6810e6
* Mode: LACP (802.3ad)
* Hash policy: layer3+4

On the switch, I created a Port Channel Group with LACP enabled in Active mode, and selected
two 2.5 Gbps ports that were connected to the server. Linux also reports that both card are detected and bonded from its own perspective:
# ip link | grep enx
3: enx00e04c6810e6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
4: enx00e04c680152: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000

Unfortunately, for some reason, Linux cannot establish an LACP link with the switch
no matter what, Linux kernel keeps telling me that "No 802.3ad response from the link
partner for any adapters in the bond".
# dmesg
[ 1004.491253] bond0: Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in the bond
[ 1034.527234] bond0: Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in the bond
[ 1064.547217] bond0: Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in the bond

The status file /proc/net/bonding/bond0 shows that IEEE 802.3ad is active, but a link is not successfully
established. This can be seen from the fact that the "Aggregator ID" for both NICs are different, and that
both of them entered "churned" state, which essentially means the link failed,
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v6.1.15-1-pve

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP active: on
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: 8a:f5:1c:f4:8b:70
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 1
    Actor Key: 10
    Partner Key: 1
    Partner Mac Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00

Slave Interface: enx00e04c680152
MII Status: up
Speed: 2500 Mbps
Duplex: half
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:e0:4c:68:01:52
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: churned
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 8a:f5:1c:f4:8b:70
    port key: 10
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 77
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 1

Slave Interface: enx00e04c6810e6
MII Status: up
Speed: 2500 Mbps
Duplex: half
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:e0:4c:68:10:e6
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 2
Actor Churn State: churned
Partner Churn State: churned
Actor Churned Count: 1
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 8a:f5:1c:f4:8b:70
    port key: 10
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 69
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 1


TL;DR
These network adapters should be switched to the vendor-specific mode (bConfigurationValue: 1) and
be controlled by Linux driver r8152. The default mode (bConfigurationValue: 2) with the generic cdc_ncm
driver has limited functionality, so not all features will work correctly.
Analysis
After multiple days of troubleshooting, I've eventually determined the root cause. The clue is hardware
information reported by ethtool:
# ethtool enx00e04c6810e6
Settings for enx00e04c6810e6:
    Supported ports: [  ]
    Supported link modes:   Not reported
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 2500Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: yes

Note how important hardware information, like auto-negotiation or supported link modes are unavailable
from the device driver. Also note how the driver claims the adapter is running in 2.5 Gbps half-duplex,
which is unusual. I suspect Linux's bonding module doesn't work due to incomplete hardware information
or feature support.
Upon further investigation, I found that by default, these Realtek 2.5 Gbps USB adapters were running in
generic USB CDC-NCM mode. This is a standard mode defined by USB, but only limited functionality is available.
To enable the full hardware features of these adapters, one must switch them from the standard mode
(bConfigurationValue: 2) to the vendor-specific mode (bConfigurationValue: 1). The current mode can be
checked by examining the file bConfigurationValue in /sys/bus/usb/devices/.
First, examine the USB hardware via lsusb and lsusb -t:
# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN

# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ncm, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ncm, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/3p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ncm, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ncm, 5000M

One can see that the driver cdc_ncm is used.
Next, make sure you're looking at the correct device in /sys/bus/usb/devices (you need to
adjust /2-2/ and 4-4 according to the output of lsusb -t) by checking the content of
manufacturer first, it should be Realtek. Then, examine the bConfigurationValue under
the same directory.
# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/manufacturer 
Realtek
# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/bConfigurationValue 
2

# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-4/manufacturer 
Realtek
# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-4/bConfigurationValue 
2

The bConfigurationValue is 2, which means it's in CDC_NCM mode. To manually switch the mode
for debugging, run:
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/bConfigurationValue 
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-4/bConfigurationValue 

After the switch, Linux will start controlling them using the r8152 driver, rather than the generic cdc_ncm
driver. In dmesg, one can see:
[ 8439.270745] r8152 2-2:1.0: load rtl8156b-2 v1 04/15/21 successfully
[ 8439.397031] r8152 2-2:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): netif_napi_add_weight() called with weight 256
[ 8439.397202] r8152 2-2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
[ 8439.397220] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[ 8439.399436] r8152 2-2:1.0 enx00e04c680152: renamed from eth0
[ 8505.003557] r8152 4-4:1.0: load rtl8156b-2 v1 04/15/21 successfully
[ 8505.044832] r8152 4-4:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
[ 8505.047901] r8152 4-4:1.0 enx00e04c6810e6: renamed from eth0

lsusb -t will also report that r8152 is now in charge of the network adapters.
# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/3p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M

If the adapters can be recognized by r8152, create a udev rule to apply it automatically (note that at this point, all adapters have been detached from bonding mode, so bonding will not work unless you manually recreate it, so it's easier to just add a udev rule and reboot).
Solution
First, find the VID and PID of the network adapter, which can vary depending on its brand.
# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN

Then create the following udev rule:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTR{idProduct}=="8156", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="1"

Save the rule as a file such as /etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb-r8152-ethernet.rules, and reboots the system.
Note that one should adjust the idVendor and idProduct here to match the VID and PID listed by lsusb.
After the switch, ethtool is able to obtain hardware information about the adapter:
# ethtool enx00e04c680152 
Settings for enx00e04c680152:
    Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
                            2500baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
                            2500baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Full
                                         2500baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 2500Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 32
    Transceiver: internal
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00007fff (32767)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol
    Link detected: yes

LACP can also be established:
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v6.1.15-1-pve

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP active: on
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: 8a:f5:1c:f4:8b:70
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 2
    Actor Key: 11
    Partner Key: 1
    Partner Mac Address: 8c:1f:64:9a:c2:5f

Slave Interface: enx00e04c680152
MII Status: up
Speed: 2500 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:e0:4c:68:01:52
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 8a:f5:1c:f4:8b:70
    port key: 11
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 8c:1f:64:9a:c2:5f
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 32768
    port number: 2
    port state: 61

Slave Interface: enx00e04c6810e6
MII Status: up
Speed: 2500 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:e0:4c:68:10:e6
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 1
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 8a:f5:1c:f4:8b:70
    port key: 11
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 8c:1f:64:9a:c2:5f
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 32768
    port number: 3
    port state: 61

